# How do I split the results of a webscrape by a class tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm developing a webscraper for a table of data found [https://web.columbus.org/Accounting,-Tax-Preparation,-Bookkeeping-Services>](https://web.columbus.org/Accounting,-Tax-Preparation,-Bookkeeping-Services%3E) . Each business entry is separated by the tag

```
           <div class="ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFT">
```

, however when I use the code below it returns the entire set of data instead of looping though each unique business listing.

```
    businessPage=str(businessInfo).split("ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFT")
          input(print(f"bus page: {businessPage}"))
          for i in businessPage:
                 input(print(f"{i} :i"))
```

businessInfo is the parsed data from the page and I find it using the code below:

```
        page=requests.get(https://web.columbus.org/Accounting,-Tax-Preparation,-Bookkeeping-Services)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
        businessInfo=soup.find('div', {"class":"ListingResults_All"})
```

How would I rewrite my code to loop through each unique business listing so I can scrape their data one at a time?  I didn't attach the output because of its size, but I can if needed.

Comment: The link to the code to scrape is   https://web.columbus.org/Accounting,-Tax-Preparation,-Bookkeeping-Services

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import Spider, SimplifiedDoc, utils, SimplifiedMain, req

html = req.get('https://web.columbus.org/Accounting,-Tax-Preparation,-Bookkeeping-Services')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
startDivs = doc.getElements('div', attr='class', value='ListingResults_All_ENTRYTITLELEFTBOX')
for start in startDivs:
    businessPage = doc.getElement('div',start=start._end)
    print (businessPage.text)
```

Result:

```
_ 8800 Lyra Drive, Suite 450Columbus, OH 43240 (614) 885-2583 Member Since: 2014
_ 180 East Broad Street, Suite 1400Columbus, OH 43215 3611(614) 221-1000 Member Since: 1960
_ 230 West Street, Suite 700Columbus, OH 43215 (614) 221-1120 Member Since: 1981
...
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm using VS code and having difficulty importing simplified_scrapy however.  Is there an alternative import that I could use or another way of scraping the data?  thanks.

Comment: @NickPicciano I also use VS code. This package needs to be installed first. pip install simplified_scrapy